# "What" or "Who" will you like to hire

Tags: single-word-requests

If i have a site where people can hire professionals like carpenters, bricklayers etc, do I ask
"What" will you like to hire or "Who" will you like to hire.

Im asking because *what* feels to me  like I am objectifying the hiree like *what would you like to buy*.On  the other hand, "Who" sounds like you know exactly who (ie the particular individual) you want to hire.

Comment: A human is not a thing. A human is a human.

Comment: You could ask "Which trade would you like to hire?". The word "trades" is often used in the UK to refer to people who practice a skill (particularly in construction) but also means the skills which they practice. If a site manager is asking an agency to recruit people for his site he might easily say "I need some trades, most urgently groundworkers and bricklayers"